# ORA-22163: left hand and right hand side collections are not of same type

Tags: oracle, plsql, type-mismatch

I have a simple type declaration and a simple function in Oracle:

```
TYPE col_sub_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);

  FUNCTION get_col_tab RETURN col_sub_type AS
    l_type  col_sub_type;
  BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_type
    FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('TABLE_1','TABLE_2');
    RETURN l_type;
END;
```

The function is also declared in the package specification so it can be used in the package body.

Later in the code I'm trying to use this function in a SQL statement, like this:

```
AND col.table_name NOT IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(get_col_tab()))
```

Package body and specification are both compiling perfecly fine, but still, when I'm trying to run the package I get:

```
ORA-22163: left hand and right hand side collections are not of same type
ORA-06512: at "PACKAGE_NAME", line 25
ORA-06512: at "PACKAGE_NAME", line 236
```

Line 25 is:

```
RETURN l_type;
```

Line 236 is the beginning of the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT col.table_name
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a minimal example that compiles and demonstrates the error as there is not enough here to work out what the issue is.

Comment: Line 25 and Line 236 doesnt always mean that the error is in these lines. Maybe the error went through along those lines so if you could share, if not the whole package, just the complete block containing Line 25 and line 236. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the type definition from the package body and create it outside

```
CREATE TYPE col_sub_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);
```

Comment: This solved the problem! But... I just got word that I cannog create global types on the database... So the problem comes back...

Answer (score 0):

You have likely defined the type `col_sub_type` twice: once in SQL context and once in PL/SQL context (in a package). The types might look the same but they are different. Your PL/SQL function uses the type defined in PL/SQL but your SQL expects the type defined in SQL.

Remove the PL/SQL definition of the type and the problem disappears.

This is related to PL/SQL and SQL engines and context switching between the engines (google for more).

Comment: I don't fully understand Your answer... and col_sub_type is defined only once in the package body... (but no trace of it in package specification. Or maybe how do I declare a type in SQL context?